# Pygame on Android: how can I double-tap to close the app without moving the rectangle

Tags: android, pygame

The code below draws a rectangle which can be moved by touching the screen. Double-tapping the screen closes the toy app. I wonder how to improve the code so that when you double-tap to quit the app, the rectangle remains unmoved.

```
import pygame


def main():
    pygame.init()
    DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500),0,32)
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, blue,(480,200,50,250))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.mouse.set_pos((480, 200))
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    timer = 0
    dt = 0
    pos = 0

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():            
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if timer == 0:
                    timer = 0.001
                    # Click again before 0.5 seconds to double click.
                elif timer < 0.5:
                    # Double click happened
                    run = False
            else:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, blue, (pos[0],pos[1], 50, 250))
                pygame.display.update()

        # Increase timer after mouse was pressed the first time.
        if timer != 0:
            timer += dt
            # Reset after 0.5 seconds.
            if timer >= 0.5:
                 timer = 0

        # dt == time in seconds since last tick.
        # / 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds.
        dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000

main()
```

Comment: *"when you double-tap to quit the app, the rectangle remains unmoved."* - When the app is quit, then the position of the rectangle is completely irrelevant. Do you mean to fix the rectangle instead of quit the app? What do I miss here? What about `if run: pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`?

Comment: I do agree that when the app is closed, the rectangle position is irrelevant. What I would like to do is to avoid that the rectangle is visually moved right before the app is closed. This is just a challenge I failed to solve.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is to avoid that the rectangle is visually moved right before the app is closed.

Immediately before the application is closed, the state of `run` is set `False`. Don't change the position of the rectangle if `run` is `False`, respectively only change it `if run:`.
To handle the double-tap you have to add the addtional condition `timer == 0`:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # [...]

            else:
                if run and timer == 0:
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, blue, (pos[0],pos[1], 50, 250))
                pygame.display.update()
```

Or even better, do not draw anything if `run` is `False`:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
                # [...]

            elif run and timer == 0:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, blue, (pos[0],pos[1], 50, 250))
                pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem since when you double tap the screen, the first tap does move the rectangle.

Comment: @Jean-PierreSchnyder then the solution is `if run and timer == 0:`